# Putting ORs into if statement results in ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer (f-permissive)

Tags: c++

I don't understand why it's reporting this error.

The error is `ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer (f-permissive)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int letters; //Total number of letters                                                                                                                                           
  int digits; //Total number of digits                                                                                                                                             
  int sentencecount; //Number of sentences                                                                                                                                         
  float averageletters; //Average number of letters per sentence                                                                                                                   
  int linecount=0; //Count of lines                                                                                                                                                
  char current; //Current character                                                                                                                                                
  sentencecount = letters/linecount;                                                         
  cin.get(current);
  while (cin) //while receiving input                                                                                                                                              
    {
      digits = 0;
      letters = 0;
      linecount++;
      if (current == "." || current == "!" || current == "?")   //checks each line                                                                                                 
        {
          if (isalpha(current))//counts alphabet characters                                                                                                                        
            letters++;
          if (isdigit(current))//counts digits                                                                                                                                     
            digits++;
          cin.get (current);
        }
      sentencecount = letters/linecount;
      cout << "avg number of letters" << sentencecount << "digits" <<  digits << endl;
      cin.get (current);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are comparing a char array (pointer) to a char. Which compares its address to the value of the char. Hence the warning. Use sinlge quotes `'`

Comment: It compiled. Thanks.

Comment: I posted it as an answer so you can close this question

Comment: Just throwing in that `char` is an `integer` type, like `short`, `int` or `long`. I find that often people new to C or C++ don't know that, and often people experienced with C or C++ forget to mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line:

```
if (current == "." || current == "!" || current == "?")
```

You are using `string literals` or to phrase it correctly `character arrays`. Which translates to a pointer to that array. i think you meant to use single quotation the mark it as a single character with `'`. That way you are value comparing it.